# Compound interest formula is not understandable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, finance, economics

I am struggling to understand the formula for compound interest. More specifically what the $n$ stands for.

The formula is as follows according to the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest):
$$
A = P(1 + \frac{r}{n})^{nt}
$$

Where
$A$ = final amount
$P$  = initial principal balance (money invested)
$r$  = interest rate
$n$  = number of times interest applied per time period
$t$  = number of time periods elapsed

But we can twist the parameters so that the interest is not $r$.

Let's take an example: annual interest rate of 20%, compounded quarterly. This means that the parameters are $t = 1$ year, $r = 20$%, $n = 4$

If I invest 1 USD for a year ($P = 1$) it should be 1.20 USD at the end of the year by the definition of annual interest rate, but based on the formula, I calculate something different: The annual interest rate is $21.55$%, because by investing 1 USD, I will have earned 1.2155 USD by the end of the year.

$$
A = 1(1 + \frac{0.2}{4})^{4 \cdot 1} = 1.21550625
$$
Which is approximately 21.55%, not 20% annually.

The continuous compounding interest is derived from this formula, so I would like to understand this before understanding that.

Comment: that's right; interest is higher when you compound more frequently. this is why APY and APR are distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An annual interest rate of $20\%$ **compounded quarterly** means what the formula reflects, namely that your investment grows once every quarter at a quarterly rate of $20\%/4=5\%.$ This is **not** the same thing as an annual interest rate of $20\%$ (no compounding), which means your investment grows once every year at the yearly rate of $20\%$.  As you have noted, the former gives an *effective annual rate* of approximately $21.55\%$ while the latter simply gives an effective annual rate of $20\%.$

Compounding more frequently thus leads to a higher annual return, i.e.

$$P(1+r/n)^{nt}\quad (1)$$

increases in $n$ for $r,t>0$. Intuitively, the exponential effect of more compounding periods outweighs the linear effect of the lower per-period interest rate. As you suggestively note, taking the limit of $(1)$ as $n\to \infty$ gives the continuous compounding formula

$$Pe^{rt}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The reason you end up with $21.55\%$ interest and not just $20\%$ is *precisely* because of the $n=4$ that you do not understand.

After the first quarter ($1/4$)of the year, the interest you earned *so far* ($20\%/4 = 5\%$) is added to your balance. Then you earn interest on that interest for the rest of the year.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=1$ then the interest is applied once per year.  So you'd get $20$ cents in your example, as you expect.  But if $n=4$, you get $1/4$ of the interest each quarter of the year.  So after $3$ months, you get $5$ cents.  But now you have \$1.05 in the account, so at the end of the next quarter, you get 5 cents of interest on the dollar, but also 5% interest on the extra nickel.  After you do this 4 times, you have "interest on the interest" adding up to an extra 1.55 cents.